# Where can I ask questions about sourcing custom displays?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a project where I am in need of a custom shaped display. I'm interested in asking something like:

> Where can I as a consumer purchase O-LED or LED screens in a custom shape and dimension such as half  of an ellipse or even ellipse?

Where could I ask questions like this that they'd be on topic?

Comment: Hey Steinar! This site is actually the best place to as "where can I ask about?" questions but it's not the right place to actually ask the question you want to ask. I've edited your question into a site recommendation question rather than a direct question since you seemed to be aware that this wasn't the right place and were looking for that place. Welcome and good luck in your search.

Comment: @SuperMegaDuckyMomo That's...incredibly unhelpful.  The question is specifically not on-topic there.  Shopping recommendations are not allowed in any sense.